# Not able to see ngModel value in PrimeNG date picker

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I used PrimeNG date picker to show only the time, I applied `ngModel` for it to show a value which comes from the server.

But that isn't working, the value which is in `ngModel` is not shown when my page is loaded.

Take a look at the code that I have written so far:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="test" timeOnly="true" (onInput)="startTime(i)" (onSelect)="startTime(i)"></p-calendar>
```

TS File :

```
check = "10:00";
```

Answer (score 1):

`test` property should be a `Date` instead of a string like in your code.

From [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) doc :

> Two-way value binding is defined using the standard ngModel directive referencing to a Date property.

Try with this piece of code :

```
test: Date;

constructor() {
  this.test = new Date();
  this.test.setHours(10,0); // 10 hours and 0 minute
}
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/51tQyP0GTA0zfyC6evqM?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let u know